# Keyboard Layout after startup reverts to "ABC - Extended" when using FileVault

Tags: keyboard, high-sierra, mojave, filevault, catalina

I am an ordinary `QWERTZ` keyboard user. Now, when I setup my mac, I neglected the Keyboard Layout setting (I thought it would default to the usual). But, the layout was set to `ABC - Extended`.

I can change it back to `QWERTZ`, but every time I restart my mac it reverts back to the ABC setting.

My keyboard does not look like this (But part of me does wish it did).

[image: abc layout]

How can I permanently change the setting of the keyboard layout at the login screen?
[image: default setting]

After updating to macOS Mojave I still have this problem, so the setting must have slipped back in through my TimeMachine backup.

The screen in macOS Mojave. There are some weird UI issues with `Dvorak - QUERTY ⌘`.

[image: weird screen]

This are my **Language and Region** settings:

[image: regional settings]

And my user settings:
[image: user settings]

The problem persisted after I have updated to macOS Catalina.

These are my keyboard settings:
[image: keyboard settings]

#### Update:

I could shed some light onto this issue. The [ctrl.blog](https://www.ctrl.blog/entry/how-to-macos-login-keyboard-layout.html), which was mentioned in the comments mentions that FileVault might plays a role in this. So these are the steps I did follow:

1. Reboot
2. "ABC - Extended" is chosen as the language at the login dialog
3. Choose German and sign in
4. Reboot
5. "ABC - Extended" is chosen as the language at the login dialog
6. Change the language and sign in
7. Disable FileVault and wait for it's completion
8. Reboot
9. The Loginscreen looks a bit different now, I'm able to scroll with the mouse wheel and I'm able to choose "Remove current from list" in the language menu.
10. Sign in and Reboot
11. **FINALLY**: The language is now still set to German.
12. Enable FileVault again (hoping that the currently set language will be used as the new Default).
13. Wait until FileVault is activated (another few hours)
14. Reboot
15. **There we go again**: ABC is again set as the default

I did submit this Feedback to Apple as of November 13 2019.

Comment: Is your keyboard connected to your Mac through a USB hub? Could you provide the keyboard manufacturer and model?

Comment: I have an apple usb keyboard and the builtin keyboard of my macbook

Comment: And you plug the USB keyboard directly to your Mac, I guess? To rule out that this issue is caused by the USB keyboard, if you set the keyboard layout to QWERTZ with the USB keyboard unplugged, restart and log in (without plugging in the keyboard), does the keyboard layout for the built-in keyboard revert to 'ABC - extended'?

Comment: @jaume, The ABC shows up as a default even when no external keyboard is connected. I always change the layout to German before I sign in (because I can't sign in otherwise).

Comment: Tried this [fix](https://www.ctrl.blog/entry/how-to-macos-login-keyboard-layout.html) already?

Comment: @klanomath Hy there, I did the steps but the gear-icon with "Apply to login screen" did not show up on my Catalina Mac. They seem to have removed that at some point down the line. I did all the other steps nonetheless, did a reboot and it did not work unfortunately.

Comment: @klanomath Yes FileVault is currently enabled

Comment: @klanomath I did read the FileVault may cause the issue. So I will try to 1. disable FileVault, set the language and then re-enable FileVault. I'll post my findings here.

Comment: In my opinion the culprit is /Volumes/Preboot/<some_UUID>/System/Library/Caches/com.apple.corestorage/EFILoginLocalizations/preferences.efires. Preboot has to be mounted manually.

Comment: @klanomath: I did find two UUIDs and they both have the file you mentioned. However, they have `en` and `en-CA` at the very end and no references about ABC.

Comment: @Besi I will check this in a Catalina-VM (not filevaulted though)...moment please. I traced changes in the file (choosing different layouts) but I didn't choose ABC...stupid me ;-)

Comment: @klanomath: This link was helpful and got me onto the fact that FileVault might play a role in this. I did get in touch with the author of that blog and he might incorporate these new findings into his guide.

Comment: Did you try [SMC](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295) and [NVRAM](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204063) reset? Sometimes when there are macOS updates, my pre-boot authentication login keyboard is also defaults back to US. My theory would be that the keyboard layout setting is stored in SMC/NVRAM and that gets reset during updates. The SMC/NVRAM sometimes does strange things (such as not store new settings) and resetting usually helps. This could be the case for you.

Comment: Another thing you could try: Boot into the recovery system by pressing cmd+D during startup. Change the keyboard layout there and see if your problem persists.

Comment: @n1000 The recovery system boots a more sophisticated UI where I can use the scroll-wheel of my mac and where I also have the option to remove any chosen languages. In the FileVault-enabled login window this is not the case.

Comment: Doing this https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/396744/15604 before enabling FileVault fixed it for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote an article called [How to fix macOS startup keyboard layout not persisting](https://www.ctrl.blog/entry/how-to-macos-login-keyboard-layout.html) about this very problem.

I never figured out exactly what the problem was, but the ABC Extended keyboard layout is the default fallback when no other keyboard layout is configured. The pre-boot environment stores its settings separately from the rest of the system.

Sometimes these settings go out of sync, or the system fails to save settings to the pre-boot environment. You’re more likely to run into this when using FileVault disk-encryption because of the increased complexity in this setup.

I lay out [11 steps](https://www.ctrl.blog/entry/how-to-macos-login-keyboard-layout.html) in the above article that gets macOS to regenerate the settings file in the pre-boot environment. With the help of my readers, I’ve identified at least three different problems that these steps can resolve. It’s easier to just diligently follow all the steps exactly than to first try to identify the exact issue and then try to fix it.

Comment: Thanks for your remarks. May I suggest to quote those eleven steps in your answer in case the link might break in the future.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use `ABC - Extended` or any other keyboard layout, you can simply remove them permanently from your list of keyboards.

1. Go to `Settings` > `Keyboard` > `Input Sources`
2. Select the keyboard you want to remove
3. Click the `-` icon at the bottom

[image: solution-pic]

Comment: There I have "Swiss German" like expected. ABC does not show up there. I would think that this is a per-user setting. Where the login screen is a system wide setting, since the user has not signed in yet.

Comment: @Besi hah, this also is happening to me and my Mac also has Swiss German as default. May be a pattern? :) Gruetzi

Answer (score -2):

Follow these steps:

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202036

We Dvorak folk have to do this all the time...

Comment: This did not work, I changed the language to "German" and ABC is still shown as the default afer a reboot.

Comment: Sigh. Sorry...sometimes even the official answer doesn't work...

Comment: I did do this and the language was changed on the next reboot, however the keyboard-layout was still set to "ABC". :-(