# How to change the default macOS login window keyboard layout?

Tags: macos, keyboard, internationalization, input-source

I type using a keyboard layout other than the standard QWERTY. This question will apply to those who type using Dvorak, Colemak, QWERTZ, or any other international or non-standard keyboard layout.

My keyboard layout (Dvorak) is different than the standard keyboard layout for my country / locale. So this question isn't simply solved by setting a default locale; I also need to specify a default keyboard layout.

When I log in to my macOS user account, my personal keyboard layout is always used. It's also selected on the Lock Screen if I ever Lock the computer.

But when *I first boot my Mac* after a Restart or Shut Down, the QWERTY keyboard layout is always selected.

I'm forced to hunt-and-peck my password because my keyboard layout is not set. Or, I can manually change the keyboard layout via the Input menu (which *is* shown, but is not the focus of this question).

How can I change the **default** keyboard layout used on the macOS login window / startup screen?

Comment: Have you  seen  https://www.ctrl.blog/entry/how-to-macos-login-keyboard-layout.html

Comment: @TomGewecke that allows me to apply a *language* to the Login Window, but I don't see a way to specify a keyboard layout within that language.

Comment: Did you try it going thru all the steps?  Step one is where the desired layout is set, the rest is supposed to make it stick.  Did it not work?

Comment: @TomGewecke *Make sure the layout you want to have on the login window is at the top of the list of keyboard layouts.* I see no way to reorder that list. In my case, `Canadian English` is always alphabetically sorted above `Dvorak`.

Comment: Try getting rid of Canadian English and everything else except Dvorak, at least for the  purpose of this process.  If you really need it, you can try adding it back later.

Comment: The correct solution is [in this blog](https://vkritis.blogspot.com/2014/01/change-default-keyboard-of-osx-login.html). TL;DR run `sudo cp ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.HIToolbox.plist /Library/Preferences/` to copy your local keyboard settings over the default root settings.

Comment: @jlyonsmith can you please add that as an Answer?

Comment: @jlyonsmith this does not appear to be working on M1Pro macs when FileVault is enabled

Comment: Just tried this again on my new M1 based Macbook Pro with FileVault enabled and it still worked for me.

Answer (score 9):

In Terminal, run this to copy your keyboard settings to the default settings:

`sudo cp ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.HIToolbox.plist /Library/Preferences/`

via [Change the default keyboard of OSX login screen permanently](https://vkritis.blogspot.com/2014/01/change-default-keyboard-of-osx-login.html)

Comment: This didn't work for me for a [keyboard layout installed from the internet](https://www.kaufmann.no/roland/dvorak/) on Big Sur 11.2.3 on a 2020 M1 MacBook Air

Comment: Didn't work on MacOS Monterey (12.1)

Answer (score -4):

The correct answer for Big Sur is here:

> How to change the keyboard layout on the MacOS login screen
>
> https://www.ctrl.blog/entry/how-to-macos-login-keyboard-layout.html