# How can I use a non-qwerty keyboard on the login page?

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, language

I have one user on my account and the language in the language and region settings is English.

I use a non-English keyboard layout, like dvorak, and I'd like for that to be default on the login page.

I have just one keyboard under input services and that is this keyboard layout.

But, when I go to login, it automatically and always uses qwerty.

Comment: See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/393662/how-to-change-the-default-macos-login-window-keyboard-layout?noredirect=1#comment541609_393662

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work. I have my non-qwerty layout as the only option listed under input sources

Comment: Did you also do all the other steps in.  https://www.ctrl.blog/entry/how-to-macos-login-keyboard-layout.html    ?